# Show that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$ for any square matrices $A,B$ of size $n$.

Tags: matrices, trace

> Let $A=(a_{i,j})$ be a square matrix of size $n$. Define $$\operatorname{tr} A :=\sum_{i=1}a_{i,i}=a_{1,1}+a_{2,2}+\cdots+a_{n,n}$$
>
> (a) Show that $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)$ for any square matrices $A,B$ of size $n$.
>
> (b) Let $B$ be an invertible square matrix of size $n$. Show that $$\operatorname{tr} \left( B^{-1} A B \right) = \operatorname{tr}A$$

How do I do this? Sorry for posting without doing any work but I have completely no idea how to even start.

Comment: Write $a_{i,j}$ and $b_{i,j}$ for the entries of $A$ and $B$. Compute the entries of $AB$ and so also its trace in terms of the $a_{i,j}$ and $b_{i,j}$ etc. You may want to do the $n=2$ case first.

Comment: Were you never told that if $C=AB$ then $c_{ij} = \sum_k a_{ik} b_{kj} \text{?}$ I.e. multiply a row on the left by a column on the right? If you know that, that it seems obvious that that's where you can start, and if you don't, then you don't have the prerequisites for this problem.

Comment: BTW, the identity $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)$ does not depend on their being square matrices. You could have $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $B\in \mathbb R^{n\times m}$ and the proposition is still true and the proof is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

Let $C=AB.$ Then $c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj}.$

So $\operatorname{tr}(C) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{ki}\right).$

Now do the same thing with $BA$ and observe that you get the same result.

You ought to be more specific about where your difficulty lies before you can expect more than what is above as an answer.

As for $\operatorname{tr}(B^{-1}AB),$ it is $\operatorname{tr}\Big( \big(B^{-1}\big)\big(AB\big) \Big).$ What was done above says you can interchange the order of multiplitation of the two matrices in the $\big( \text{intermediate-sized round brackets} \big)$ and get $\operatorname{tr}\Big( \big(AB\big)\big(B^{-1}\big)\Big).$ Then simplify that.

Comment: Another way to approach part b would be to recall that as $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $B$ an invertible $n \times n$ matrix, then $B^{-1}AB = C$, where $C$ is matrix similar to $A$.

Comment: @Duncan : How is that "another approach"? That can't work unless you first have a proved proposition saying similar matrices have equal traces, and the seemingly obvious way to prove that is to prove first that $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA).$ If you use the two propositions to prove each other, then that is circular.

Comment: Could you not use that characteristic polynomials of similar matrices are identical?

Comment: @Duncan : You can use things like that if you've proved those. But a straightforward proof of the proposition proposed here is so simple that making it depend on more complicated things (like the definition and properties of determinants) seems perverse and perhaps misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C := AB$ and $D := BA$. Matrix multiplication is defined "entry-wise", with $c_{ij} := \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}$, and $d_{ij} := \sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}a_{kj}$. Thus

$$c_{ii} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{ki}$$

and

$$d_{ii} = \sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}a_{ki}\,.$$

So $$\mathrm{tr}(C) := \sum_{i=1}^n c_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{ki}$$
and
$$\mathrm{tr}(D) := \sum_{i=1}^n d_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}a_{ki} =  \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n b_{ik}a_{ki} =  \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ki} b_{ik},$$

where the two last equalities follow from the independence of the sum signs and commutativity of products (I assume your ring is commutative). Interchanging the $k, i$ symbols in $\mathrm{tr}(D)$, we get $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{ki} = \mathrm{tr}(C)$. From the definition of $C, D$, we get

$$\mathrm{tr}(AB) = \mathrm{tr}(AB). \quad\square$$

Given this theorem, $\mathrm{tr}(B^{-1}AB) = \mathrm{tr}((B^{-1}A)B) = \mathrm{tr}(B(B^{-1}A)) = \mathrm{tr}((BB^{-1})A) = \mathrm{tr}(IA) = \mathrm{tr}A$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

With

$A = [a_{ij}], \tag 1$

$B = [b_{ij}], \tag 2$

we have

$(AB)_{ij} = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}; \tag 3$

$(BA)_{ij} = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^n b_{ik}a_{kj}; \tag 4$

then

$\text{tr}(AB) = \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^n (AB)_{ii} = \sum_{i = 1}^n  \sum_{k = 1}^n a_{ik}b_{ki}$
$= \displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^n \sum_{i = 1}^n b_{ki}a_{ik} = \sum_{k = 1}^n (BA)_{kk} = \text{tr}(BA).  \tag 5$

We can use this result to show that with $B$ invertible

$\text{tr}(B^{-1}AB) = \text{tr}(A), \tag 6$

for

$\text{tr}(B^{-1}AB) =  \text{tr}(B^{-1}(AB))$
$=  \text{tr}((AB)B^{-1}) = \text{tr}(A(BB^{-1})) = \text{tr}(AI) = \text{tr}(A). \tag 7$

***Note Added in Edit, Sunday 29 December 2019 1:09 PM PST:***  I think it is worth observing that *any* function $\sigma$ of $n \times n$ matrices such that

$\sigma(AB) = \sigma(BA) \tag 8$

is itself a similarity invariant; that is, for invertible $B$,

$\sigma(B^{-1}AB) = \sigma(A); \tag 9$

the proof of this simply follows (7):

$\sigma(B^{-1}AB) = \sigma(B^{-1}(AB))$
$= \sigma((AB)B^{-1}) = \sigma(A(BB^{-1})) = \sigma(AI) = \sigma(A). \tag{10}$

Furthermore, the implication

$(9) \Longrightarrow (7) \tag{11}$

also binds, since

$\sigma(AB) = \sigma(I(AB)) = \sigma((B^{-1}B)AB) = \sigma(B^{-1}(BA)B) = \sigma(BA). \tag{12}$

***End of Note***.